# The remote name could not be resolved error

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I am working on a legacy application which is a mix of  C++, C++/CLI and C#(used to create an assembly). The assembly is referenced by C++, C++/CLI project to send/receive http request.  The legacy application is a windows service. The problem I am facing now is that httpRequest is throwing the following exception from Windows service.

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'ebqa-qa.xxxx.360.io'

I tried pinging the url from the command prompt it is also saying that it cannot find the domain.

But in a standalone C# application it is working just fine without any issues.

Can anyone please tell me what could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Perhaps it's useful to explore how that C# application resolves a hostname that's unknown to the underlying operating system.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There is no much difference , I can see.  Is there any special way i can debug that? Both application using same assembly(dll) to send the http request.

Comment: If testing on more than 1 computer has the `hosts` file been edited ?